# "fe_sendauth: no password supplied" During pg_upgrade Process

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgresql-11, postgresql-14, pg-upgrade

I'm encountering an error "fe_sendauth: no password supplied" while attempting to run pg_upgrade to migrate from PostgreSQL 11 to 14. I've set up a .pgpass file with the password and configured the PGPASSFILE environment variable.
During the execution of pg_upgrade, an error occurred while attempting to start the old server using the following command.

---

### Performing Consistency Checks

Checking cluster versions                                   ok

fe_sendauth: no password supplied

could not connect to source postmaster started with the command:

"/home/postgres/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/home/postgres/data" -o "-p 5433 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories='/home/'" start

---

When initiating the server with this command locally, the PostgreSQL server starts up without any apparent issues with password authentication. However, when attempting to use pg_upgrade, the error persists.

I've attempted to replace "localhost" with the Unix socket directories in the pgpass file and have also tried setting both PGHOST and PG_UNIX_SOCKET_DIR environment variables, but the issue remains unresolved.

The pg_upgrade command I used:
./pg_upgrade --check --link (I exported all the env variables for data and bin directory, port, user and pgpassfile)

I don't want to change pg_hba.conf file to add a 'method' 'trust' for localhost.

I've explored various solutions online, but unfortunately, none of them have resolved the issue for me.

Comment: The error is not when the server starts up, it is when you try to connect to it after the server has successfully started.  Your .pgpass file must not be working for some reason, like one of the host, user, port, etc., does not match.

Comment: @jjanes After successfully starting the PostgreSQL server using the specified command with the unix_socket_directories parameter set to /home/sas, I attempted to connect to the server using psql. However, the connection attempt failed with the following error message:

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433"?

Comment: @jjanes Upon further investigation, I observed that the PostgreSQL server was not listening on port 5433 as expected. When inspecting the active ports using the netstat command (netstat -tuln), port 5433 was not listed among the active ports.
Despite configuring the unix_socket_directories parameter to /home/sas, it appears that the server is utilizing the /tmp/ directory for Unix domain socket connections instead.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_upgrade` starts the servers on a different port and connects to them using Unix sockets. Your password file must match that, for example

```
localhost:*:*:postgres:mypassword
```

The alternative is to modify `pg_hba.conf` so that `postgres` is allowed to connect locally without a password.

Comment: The format of my pgpass file "hostname:port:dbname:user:password".

Comment: Right, that's why it doesn't work.